# how to detect all keys affected by sliding movements in KeyboardView (android)

Tags: android

When you press a key on a soft keyboard and then move to another key and finally pull up your finger, the only thing that happens is that the last character is printed out. Now I need to detect all keys between the path. For example there are three keys: 'w', 'e' and 'r' between 'q' and 't'. How can I detect them when the user presses 'q' and moves to 't' and then releases ir?

Comment: The "detection" is done by the keyboard.  Therefore, you must create your own keyboard.

Comment: I've already created one. Just tell me how on the earh I can catch those focused keys.